# Remove only first and last separator on react native flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to display a flatlist with a header component, but can't seem to remove the first and last separators.

This is how I'm currently rendering the items.

```
renderSeparator = () => (
    <Separator
        marginTop="$unitOne"
        marginBottom="$unitOne"
    />
)

render() {
    const { newsData } = this.props;
    return (
        <Container>
          {newsData.length > 0
            ? (
              <FlatList
                data={newsData}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  item.featured === null && this.renderNews(item)
                )}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                style={styles.container}
                ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                ListHeaderComponent={this.renderFeaturedNews}
              />
            )
            : <Placeholder />
          }
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that will work for you;

```
          <FlatList
            data={newsData}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              item.featured === null && this.renderNews(item)
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            style={styles.container}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={(index===0 || index === newsData.length - 1) ? null : this.renderSeparator}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderFeaturedNews}
          />
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  index is scoped to renderItem.  It doesn't exist for ItemSeparatorComponent.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know what was the situation with `FlatList` when this question was asked but right now `ItemSeparatorComponenet` won't be generated for last and first.

> Rendered in between each item, but not at the top or bottom

Read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent)